# Is it permitted to cut hair before janaba bath?

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, taharah

Last week, I had to perform janaba bath. Then I began to cut nails before going to bath(that day is a friday). But, my friend stopped me to cut off the nails.

He said that

> it is not permitted in Islam to cut nails or hair in the situation
>   when janaba bath is in fard.

Is it so?

Comment: There is no references in islamic law on it.
But based on Imam Hanafi hate the shaved hair or nail in the case of janaabah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, as El BOKAHRY commented in the book of ghosl (one of biggest textbooks on this topic) chapter 24 (وقال عطاء يحتجم الجنب ويقلم أظفاره ويحلق رأسه وإن لم يتوضأ). Which means that you are permitted to cut your hair or nails even if you didn't do ablution